# Can no longer insert images into a page?

Tags: 2010, content-editor-web-part, image

I have a page that I have been editing successfully, adding web parts and configuring. Unfortunately now, for whatever reason when I go to insert an image the browser locks up. This is happening on multiple machines, with different accounts, on multiple browsers. Whatever causes this? Is there a way I can fix it? Nothing custom is installed, except for Nintex and ControlPoint, which I don't believe should be impacting on this.

Comment: does browser shows a javascript error??

Comment: @DeepikaTyagi No, nothing